# How to disconnect any clients still connected and close the server?

Tags: java, multithreading, server, server-side

I have to implement (in the server side) the quit command which disconnects any clients still connected and closes the server.

Here the server code.

```
public class Server {
    
    public static void main (String args []) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java Server <port>");
            return;
        }
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        try {
            ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(port);
            Files input = new Files();
            
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Listening...");
                Socket s = listener.accept();
                System.out.println("Connected");

                Thread clientHandlerThread = new Thread(new ClientHandler(s,input));
                clientHandlerThread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error during I/O operation:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

how can the server accept command line instructions while it is running?

Comment: What stops you from just invoking `System.exit()`? It will terminate the server process, which causes all sockets to be closed and the clients would get a notification that their peer terminated the connection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to keep track of all the clients that you create by putting their instances in a list so that when you're going to shutdown everything, you could access them and tell them to finish their job.

And about how to tell the thread instances to do that, you should call their `interrup()` method to inform them that they should finish/stop whatever it's doing. Calling the `interrupt()` method on a thread leads an `InterruptedException` in the thread that you should handle and gracefully finish whatever you're doing.

For example if you have something like this in the run method of your `ClientHandler`:

```java
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(interval);
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        System.out.println(
                "We've been asked to finish up the communication. Bye! ;)");
    }
    // do your business
}
```

This was of course a very simplified scenario to demonstrate the overall approach. You should be able to find tons of tutorials online about how to use the interrupt.